# The use of the question "how much is this" in context

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Let's say my friend has bought a phone. And I want to buy the same phone, not from my friend, but at a phone store. Is natural to ask my friend *how much is the phone*? Would it be more natural to ask him *how much does the phone cost*? I think that you ask the question *hom much is something* only when you are at a store asking the shop assistant about the price. Being a non-native English speaker it is hard to tell whether the question *how much is something* sounds natural when you are asking your friends.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, if you turn to your friend and ask him

> How much is this?

It sounds like you are asking him its price, as if he were to sell you. A better approach would be

> How much did you pay for this phone?
> How much was it?